# How to delay css animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I delay my animation in jQuery? I tried using setTimeout, but it isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').hover(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).css('transform', 'scale(1.3, 1.3)');
    },500);

  }, function(){
    $(this).css('transform', 'none');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7w8kL59v/4/

Answer (score 3):

While there was a nifty [CSS example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622931/how-to-delay-css-animation-in-jquery/39623022#39623022) provided as an alternate answer, for your specific case, I would advise against it. The reason being is that the animation - although delayed - is still initialized on hover, and because your transition involves `scale`, it makes the text blurry during the delay period.

Regarding the Javascript solution, once you go into the `setTimeout`, you lose the scope of `$(this)`. I would declare it prior to your `setTimeout` and then use that declaration rather than `$(this)`, like so...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').hover(function(){
    var myButton = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      myButton.css('transform', 'scale(1.3, 1.3)');
    },500);

  }, function(){
     myButton.css('transform', 'none');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve want you want is to use only CSS, mainly the `transition` property.

It was already demonstrated by [5aledmaged in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39623022/3928341)

---

Here's a JS solution:

The reason it doesn't work is because `this` within the callback you pass into `setTimeout` is not the same as `this` within the callback you pass into `.hover()`.

```
$('button').hover(function() {
    var outer = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      outer === this; // false
    }, 500);
    // ...
```

What you can do is save a reference to the outer `this` and use it in the inner callback:

```
var $this = $(this); // save the `this` you need
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $this.css('transform', 'scale(1.3, 1.3)'); // and use it here
}, 500);
```

Demo:

```js
$('button').hover(function() {
  var $self = $(this); // save the `this` you need
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $self.css('transform', 'scale(1.3, 1.3)'); // and use it here
  }, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).css('transform', 'none');
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 50px 0 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Check
</button>
```

Or use an arrow function which maintains its outer context:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
  $(this).css('transform', 'scale(1.3, 1.3)'); // `this` is the same as outer `this`
}, 500);
```

Demo:

```js
$('button').hover(function() {
  var $self = $(this); // save the `this` you need
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(1.3, 1.3)'); // `this` is the same as outer `this`
  }, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).css('transform', 'none');
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 50px 0 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Check
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the whole effect without jQuery. Just use CSS:

```
button {
    margin: 50px 0 0 200px;
    transition: transform 1s ease .5s; /* delay equals .5s */
}

button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

Here's an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7w8kL59v/9/).

Comment: The issue with using a CSS only approach in this instance is that it still initializes the 'animation state' the instant the hover begins. Because the animation is changing `scale`, the text becomes blurry. While this isn't noticeable during animation, the 0.5s delay period makes it a bit more pronounced.

Comment: Thanks, but I want practice with JS.

Comment: For a JS solution, check @nem035's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the value of `this`. It's changing with the `setTimeout`. You can obtain the proper object by storing `this` in a variable, and then using a closure:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').hover(function(){
    var trueThis = this; // <--
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $(trueThis).css('transform', 'scale(1.3, 1.3)'); // <--
    },500);

  }, function(){
    $(this).css('transform', 'none');
  });
});
```